# Onclick redraw the chart with new values in bar chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

```js
// Dynamic Chart for bar Chart
$(function () {
  (function(H) { 
    var each = H.each;
    H.wrap(H.seriesTypes.column.prototype, 'drawPoints', function(proceed) {
      var series = this;
      if(series.data.length > 0 ){
        var width = series.barW > series.options.maxPointWidth ? series.options.maxPointWidth : series.barW;
        each(this.data, function(point) {
          point.shapeArgs.x += (point.shapeArgs.width - width) / 2;
          point.shapeArgs.width = width;
        });
      }
      proceed.call(this);
    })


  })(Highcharts)


  var getRandomData = function(size, addition) {
    if (!addition) addition = 5;
    var data = [];
    var len = Math.random() * size + addition;
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      data.push(Math.random() * 50);
    }
    return data;
  };




  $('#bar-charts').highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: 'column'
    },
    series: [{
      maxPointWidth: 50,
      data: getRandomData(5)
    }]
  });

});
$('#reloadBar').click(function () {
  // body...
  $("#bar-charts").highcharts().reflow();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="panel panel-shadow">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div id="bar-charts"></div>
    <a class="btn btn-success" id="reloadBar"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I was trying to `redraw()` the HighChart `onclilck` `reload` but was not getting any output, Don't know what mistake am doing. :?
Can some one help me how to get the random data `onclick` `reload` button

Heres the Updated Fiddle link:
https://jsfiddle.net/zeasts/tk3d3yen/

Thanks in Advance

## Zeasts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update Highchart's data manually, use [`Series.setData`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Series.setData) like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/wiltsc/tk3d3yen/3/).

Answer (score 2):

highchart's `redraw`, redraws chart with its current settings and data, to draw chart with new settings or data do the following steps:

1. define a method to the recreate chart:

   ```
   var resetChart = function(){
      $('#bar-charts').highcharts({
          chart: {
             type: 'column'
          },
          series: [{
            maxPointWidth: 50,
            data: getRandomData(5)
          }]
     });
   };
   ```
2. Call the method to create the chart at beginning.

   ```
   resetChart();
   ```
3. Define click handler like bellow and keep in mind that you should first destroy existing chart using highchart's `destroy` method and then call `resetChart` to draw new one:

   ```
   $('#reloadBar').click(function () {
       $("#bar-charts").highcharts().destroy();
       resetChart();
   });
   ```

**[Working Sample On Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hsh85/tk3d3yen/2/)**

Thanks to Wilts C, as he mentioned in his answer if you only want to change data you can also use `series[index].setData` method like this:

```
$("#bar-charts").highcharts().series[0].setData(getRandomData(5),true);
```

**[Working Sample On Fiddle With setData](https://jsfiddle.net/hsh85/tk3d3yen/7/)**

hope that helps.

Comment: when the bars are updating the new data, can I get the Animate ?

Comment: @RiotZeastCaptain, in the second approach if you set fixed  `len` you'll have a nice animation like [This](https://jsfiddle.net/hsh85/tk3d3yen/8/)  but if you need animation like the first time drawing you should use the first approach